# How to use neo4j-import?

Tags: csv, neo4j

I am new to neo4j and I have downloaded its community version on my mac. I would like to use the neo4j-import command to import a csv file. I found on the documentation of Neo4j that I should write on the command line the following:
neo4j-import --into path_to_target_directory --nodes movies4-header.csv

I am just wondering, can anybody tell me what should be the path_to_target_directory? I mean is it in the /bin folder of the community file that i unzipped or is it in the data folder?

Your help will be much appreciated :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put it anywhere, but I'd put it into the `data/graph.db` directory. Assuming you don't have anything important in your `data/graph.db` directory:

```
rm -rf data/graph.db
./bin/neo4j-import --into data/graph.db --nodes movies4-header.csv
```

Then start neo4j and you'll be starting `data/graph.db` by default, assuming you haven't changed any of your config:

```
./bin/neo4j start
```

Comment: thank you very much Nicole :) So I tried it, but they say I have an error. I typed ./bin/neo4j-import --into data/graph.db --nodes movies.csv                   and the error message in the command line says:                                   Input error: Expected '--nodes' to have at least 1 item, but had 0 ([])

Comment: Can you type `head movies.csv` and show what you see?

Comment: when I type: head movies.csv they say: No such file or directory. I actually have this file(movies.cvs) in the desktop, shall I put it in the main folder that contains all the files maybe? It is called my-neo4j and it contains bin, data, conf, lib, plugins, system.

Comment: You'll need to either move the csv file into the `my-neo4j` directory, or you'll need to use its path, `~/Desktop/movies.csv`.

Comment: oh wow it worked ! I have put the movies.csv in the main folder then i ran the same command and it worked this time. they said: IMPORT DONE in 1s 889ms. Imported:
  2 nodes
  0 relationships
  0 properties                                                                                                       Thank you so much Nicole :)

Comment: I have another question please :) After I imported the csv files into the database, how can I see the data? In other terms, is it possible to visualize a graph representation using  the neo4j web server client (localhost:7474) ? I also read that neo4j-shell enables us to write queries and save them into the db. Is that another alternative like importing csv files?